# Who decides on a site's content policy?

Tags: discussion, scope, policy

Why are there different content policies on different sites?

For example: homework-like questions are strongly discouraged on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and are immediately put on hold. Such questions however are asked a lot in [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and are quickly answered. Why is there such a different content policy on the different sites?

Are the content policies standardized for all sites or are they decided by the site moderators?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The scope of each site is determined by the community. Scope is a fluid, constantly-changing thing, and new meta discussions brought up by users can change bits and pieces of it over time, with the result decided by community consensus. Each community is independent from the others, and as such, they can shape their scope in whatever ways they want.

Physics and Mathematics both have [very specific](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/56299) [homework policies](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/170257). Both sites require a user to show what they've done so far in an attempt to solve their problem, rather than just asking the community to do their homework for them. Many questions we get on those sites *don't* meet that particular hurdle, and are closed as off-topic.

One difference that I've noticed - and which is codified in the meta FAQ for Physics - is that Physics prefers *conceptual* homework questions, rather than questions about calculation errors. Doing computations is definitely a big part of physics, but there's a point where figuring out where a user went wrong becomes a simple math problem. Physics SE is much more focused on questions where the user has a specific conceptual difficulty about the physical aspects of the problem, and as such is quick to close many questions that simply ask where a user went wrong plugging in numbers.

Comment: *Mathematics* has a homework policy, but by and large they don't follow it. They [gladly accept *any* straight homework dump](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383557) (closed a day later, but not before 7 answers were posted).

Comment: I think its also worth looking at the bigger picture.People dumping their homework, unmodified, expecting their work to be done for them is bad.
No one earns anything.On the other hand Q&A sites are really good at helping you out of the *rut*. Homework policies are there, to a large extent to ensure heathy sites. A few sites have have had much too much drama iver them

Comment: @PeterMortensen Actually, a large number of members of *Mathematics* spend some time each day eliminating such questions. Why do you think that you had to go a year and half back in order to find such an example?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos "Large" is irrelevant here. Here is some food for thought: at least one current math.se mod actively answers problem-statement-questions (some other former mods did that as well). Not a simple user, but a mod. What does this tell you?

Comment: @Did That we're gone to the dogs? Now, seriously, do you agree or not that we (at *Mathematics*) “gladly accept *any* straight homework dump”? I think that this is a gross exaggeration.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry but I provided a **fact**. Yes, a portion of users are trying to straighten the sorry situation the site has fallen to (and you know I am), but to negate the nature of the current situation is not helping to correct it. Again: a current mod and several former mods.

Comment: @Did I cannot comment on the fact, since I don't know who that curent mod is (although I have a suspect in mind) or who the former mods are (and there I have no suspects), but, from what I know about you, I think that it is quite likely that I would agree with you if I knew who they are. And, of course, it is terrible if it's true.Now, please answer my question: do you agree or not that the assertion that we “gladly accept any straight homework dump” is a gross exaggeration?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The answer depends on who is "we". Is "we" the users active on CRUDE, or the complete list of math.se users? My impression is that the users who see the site as a "straight homework dump” are (currently and despite the efforts you are referring to) a large majority. Note however that we are coming back from worse, since there was a time when invoking any kind of quality control was a sure way to pass for a fascistic elitist pathological control-freak. Now, there is at least a debate about whether one is that, or not... :-)

Comment: @Did Then I guess that I am not from that time (I've been a user since May 2017). and I meant we as a community (with more weight to the more active members, whether or not they participate on CRUDE).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry to say but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072274/some-difficult-question-about-combinatorics?noredirect=1#comment6334141_3072274) is another recent question which is just a check my work type question. You can also see that the accepted answer is the complete solution.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If such a question was posted on Physics SE, it would have been downvoted by the users and closed by the mods. I literally posted this question after seeing this one.

Comment: @harshit54 I made no mention to such questions. All my comments were about questions which can be described as dumping homework. That's not the case here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I guess you are right. But still providing a complete solution to the question is against the site's policies.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I don't think "gross exaggeration" is quite the right diagnosis, but it *is* a profound overgeneralization that betrays a total ignorance of the math.se community discussion on the matter. It fails to take that into account entirely. *Gladly* does make it sound like it is encouraged, which couldn't be further from the truth. *Unfortunately,* the fruits of effort of people who answer homework-statement questions go a long way to give the impression such questions are accepted, however.

Comment: @rschwieb That's a fine description of the current situation.